# Why does Go return a pointer to an error wrapper but declare it with "error" rather than "*error"

Tags: go

I am learning Go lang from a Java background.

```
type MyError struct {
    message string
    Offset  int
}

func (Me *MyError) Error() string {
    return Me.message
}

func myFunction() (int, error) {      <-- Why the return type is "error" rather than "*error"
    return 0, &MyError{"my error message", 0} <-- The error is returned as a pointer.
}

func main() {
    var _, err = myFunction()
    if e, ok := err.(*MyError); ok {.  <-- Why I can assert err which is a type of "error" into a pointer
        fmt.Printf("Error is %s: %d\n", e.message, e.Offset)
    }
}
```

In the code above, I don't understand why myFunction's error type is "error" rather than "*error"? I am clearly returns a pointer to MyError struct in the line below.

I also understand why I can assert the err in the main function back to a pointer.

Comment: Type `error` is an __interface__ type. Type `*MyError` implements that interface thanks to the `Error() string` method. A type assertion _asserts_ that the interface value (in this case `err`) holds a value of the specified type (in this case `*MyError`).

Comment: You should take the Tour of Go, especially starting from here: https://go.dev/tour/methods/9. It talks about interfaces, type assertions, as well as errors.

Comment: You „never“ use pointers to interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the conventional error handling in Go, you should understand how interfaces work in the language first. There are two things to keep in mind when talking about Go interfaces:

1. An interface in Go defines a set of methods (and starting at [Go1.18](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.18#generics) a set of types too). Behind the scenes, a Go interface holds two elements, a type `T` and a value `V`. `V` is *always* a concrete type such as `int`, `struct` or pointer, never an interface itself.
2. There's no `implements` keyword in Go. A Go type satisfies an interface by implementing the methods of that interface. It's called *implicit* implementation.

### Error handling

Go defines a built in `error` type, which is just an interface:

```golang
type error interface {
    Error() string
}
```

In fact, there's nothing special about it except it's a globally [predeclared type](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Predeclared_identifiers). That type is conventionally used for error handling.

To your example:

```golang
func myFunction() (int, error) {
    return 0, &MyError{"my error message", 0}
}

func main() {
    var _, err = myFunction()
    if e, ok := err.(*MyError); ok {
        fmt.Printf("Error is %s: %d\n", e.message, e.Offset)
    }
}
```

> Why the return type is "error" rather than "*error"?

The relation between the pointer to `MyError` and the `error` interface happens under the cover, you don't need to explicitly return `*error` to have a reference to `MyError` from the `error` value (actually, you [almost *never* need a pointer to an interface](https://go.dev/doc/faq#pointer_to_interface)).

After returning `myFunction`, the `error` value will hold, schematically, the following tuple `(V=&MyError{message: "my error message", Offset: 0}, T=*MyError)`, where `V` is the value it hold, and `T` is the type of the value `V`.

> Why I can assert err which is a type of "error" into a pointer

Because Go allows you to type assert on interface values. Basically what you are asking Go with the operation `e, ok := err.(*MyError)` is: Does the `err` value (which type is an `error` interface) holds the type `*MyError` as its underlying `T`? If so, `ok` will be `true`, and `e` will receive its underlying `V` value `&MyError{message: "my error message", Offset: 0}`.

**Note**: Be cautious with `nil` error values, [as they may not always behave as expected due to interface nuances](https://go.dev/doc/faq#nil_error).